# How do I get the bottom-right X & Y of a rotated triangle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, physics, trigonometry

I am trying to create a triangle that can rotate between 0° - 360° using JavaScript and then draw this to a canvas.

The origin of the triangle is 1/2 height and 1/2 width (so in the center). The triangle will rotate relative to the origin.

I have worked out the position of point A (top of the triangle) from the origin (center of the triangle) using the following code

```
    let aX = Math.cos(radians) * origin.x - Math.sin(radians) * origin.y;
    let aY = Math.sin(radians) * origin.x + Math.cos(radians) * origin.y;
```

Now, I need to find the x & y position of point B (bottom right of triangle).

The information I have to work with is:

- θ = whatever angle (in this case it is 90°)
- Origin = [0,0]
- Point A = calculation as above.  In this case [0,50]
- Height = 100
- Width = 50

How can I find the x & y position of point B taking into consideration the angle to rotate?

I have tried

```
let bX = Math.cos(radians) * Width/2 + Math.sin(radians) * Height/2;
let bY = Math.sin(radians) * Width/2 - Math.cos(radians) * Height/2;
```

but this returned

[image]

*note ignore the inverted angle

[image]

Comment: Your notation with Origin at various places is confusing. I bet this is why you have trouble dealing with the point A, though the rotation equation is valid for B as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use canvas I would recommend using `getTransform()` which returns the transform matrix that you can use to update you vertices. Here is a snippet showing the updated vertices while the triangle is being rotated.

As you'll see in this snippet I first calculate my centroid using the passed in values. Then I can subtract that amount from each vertex in order to get the transform origin to the center of the triangle.

To move the triangle around use `this.translate()`. You could also pass in those values as an argument. Using `setTransform()` we can pass in the rotation value and translate amounts and assigning `getTransform()` to a variable allows us to pass that to a function that will calculate the new vertex position.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

class Triangle {
  constructor(ptA, ptB, ptC) {
    this.ptA = ptA;
    this.ptB = ptB;
    this.ptC = ptC;
    this.translate = {x: 155, y: 100 };
    this.centroid = {
      ox: (this.ptA.x + this.ptB.x + this.ptC.x) / 3,
      oy: (this.ptA.y + this.ptB.y + this.ptC.y) / 3
    };
    this.c = "red";
    this.a = 0;
    this.rotation = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    this.pts = [];
  }
  draw() {
    let t;
    this.a -= 0.5;
    this.rotation = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    const cos = Math.cos(this.rotation)
    const sin = Math.sin(this.rotation)
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.setTransform(cos, sin, -sin, cos, this.translate.x, this.translate.y);
    t = ctx.getTransform();
    ctx.moveTo(this.ptA.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptA.y - this.centroid.oy);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptB.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptB.y - this.centroid.oy)
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptC.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptC.y - this.centroid.oy);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptA.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptA.y - this.centroid.oy);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
    this.updateVertices(t);
  }
  drawVertices() {
    for (let i=0; i < this.pts.length; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.arc(this.pts[i].x, this.pts[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
  }
  updateVertices(t) {
    //Explanation:
    //t is a variable for getTransform() passed in from draw() method.
    //The 7th and 8th arguments are the original point of where the vertex is drawn for that point. The 9th and 10th arguments are how mush the shap has been translated by.
    this.pts[0] = calcVertices(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e, t.f, this.ptA.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptA.y - this.centroid.oy, this.translate.x, this.translate.y)
    this.pts[1] = calcVertices(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e, t.f, this.ptB.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptB.y - this.centroid.oy, this.translate.x, this.translate.y) 
    this.pts[2] = calcVertices(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e, t.f, this.ptC.x - this.centroid.ox, this.ptC.y - this.centroid.oy, this.translate.x, this.translate.y)
  }
}
let triangle = new Triangle({ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 50, y: 60 }, { x: 0, y: 100 })

function calcVertices(a, b, c, d, e, f, pX, pY, cx, cy) {
  //pX and pY are the original vertex points
  let x, y;
  x = (e + pX - cx) * a + (f + pY - cy) * c + (e);
  y = (e + pX - cx) * b + (f + pY - cy) * d + (f);
  
  return {x: x, y: y}
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  triangle.draw();
  triangle.drawVertices();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Point **B** has initial coordinates `(Width/2, -Height/2)`, so after rotation

```
let bX = Math.cos(radians) * Width/2 + Math.sin(radians) * Height/2;
let bY = Math.sin(radians) * Width/2 - Math.cos(radians) * Height/2;
```

for point **C** change sign of the first terms (with  `- Width/2`)

Comment: Thanks, this has got me close to what I am after, but it seems to be drawing in the wrong place.  (see updated post).  Is this relative to the origin or point A?

Comment: You can view the actual implementation at https://minlopalis.github.io/rotating-arrow/
 and If your interested the code is at https://github.com/minlopalis/rotating-arrow.git  
I am building off another project so the code is a little messy I am planning to refactor later.

Comment: I was in doubt because you are using `origin` in some senses. This answer refers to the picture, where **coordinates zero** is in the center of triangle, and triangle rotates about it. Expanded formulas for rotation about arbitrary point have been already given by H. Rittich.

Comment: Thanks your code was really good, my solution essentially used your code except the width and the height and addition and subtraction were switched.  I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: `width and the height were switched`  - perhaps you have strange coordinate system with OX axis up

Comment: yes, I made the "degress to radians" conversion negative to make it more natural when rotating, so when rotating 90° my arrow point up rather than pointing down.

Comment: If your interested in the final result, you can see my implementation at https://minlopalis.github.io/rotating-arrow/ as you can see, it is working as expected.  Although, I need to do some major refactoring...but this can wait for another day

Answer (score 0):

The formula for rotating an arbitrary point `p` round a point `c` is

```
qₓ = cos(θ) * (pₓ - cₓ) - sin(θ) * (pᵧ - cᵧ) + cₓ
qᵧ = sin(θ) * (pₓ - cₓ) + cos(θ) * (pᵧ - cᵧ) + cᵧ ,
```

where `q` is the resulting point. You can derive this formula as follows.

It is known (see [[Wikipedia Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions)]), that rotating a point `a` around the origin, gives a point `b` where

```
bₓ = cos(θ) * aₓ - sin(θ) * aᵧ
bᵧ = sin(θ) * aₓ + cos(θ) * aᵧ .
```

You obtain the desired formula, by first moving the whole figure, such that the center of rotation is moved to the origin, i.e.,

```
aₓ = pₓ - cₓ
aᵧ = pᵧ - cᵧ .
```

Then, you apply the rotation, and afterwards, you move everything back, i.e.,

```
qₓ = bₓ - cₓ
qᵧ = bᵧ - cᵧ .
```

---

Assuming that `Bx` and `By` contain the coordinates of `B` before the rotation and `origin.x` and `origin.y` contain the coordinates of the origina, you obtain the coordinates of `B` after rotation using the following code.

```
Bx_new = Math.cos(theta) * (Bx - origin.x) - Math.sin(theta) * (By - origin.y) + origin.x
By_new = Math.sin(theta) * (Bx - origin.x) + Math.cos(theta) * (By - origin.y) + origin.y
```

If I understand your sketch correctly, you would have:

```
let origin = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
let Bx = width/2.0
let By = -height/2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when you use `p` are you referring to the position of point B? And does `c` refer to the origin?  or am I way off track?  Due to my lack of experience with math's I'm having a little trouble translating your amazing reply into my code.

Comment: Also, I could be wrong but should `qᵧ = sin(θ) * (pₓ - cₓ) + sin(θ) * (pᵧ - cᵧ) + cᵧ` actually be `qᵧ = sin(θ) * (pₓ - cₓ) + cos(θ) * (pᵧ - cᵧ) + cᵧ` ?

Comment: @minlopalis Indeed. There was an error in the formula. Yes, `p` is the position of the point that you want to transform and `c` is the origin.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me find my solution.  I appreciate your efforts with this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using the following code:

```
let bX = origin.x + Math.cos(radians) * -height / 2 - Math.sin(radians) * -width / 2
let bY = origin.y + Math.sin(radians) * -height / 2 + Math.cos(radians) * -width / 2
```